# How to add new entry to ad blocker lists?

Tags: adblock

If I find a new tracking script or ad server url, I know how I can add it to my ad blocker but how do I add it to the wider lists used but other people and other ad blockers?

Answer (score 1):

you can go here [easylist forums](http://forums.lanik.us/)  and go to the section report unblocked content. There are other sites for the other lists but easylist is one of the more widely used ones.